# what is the probability that the rows of a matrix sum to a given vector?

Tags: matrices

Given a random matrix of 1s and 0s with the upper half set to zeros, as shown:

$$
\left(
\begin{eqnarray}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 
\end{eqnarray}
\right)$$

Furthermore, assume the sums of each column are given  In the above case, that would be:

$$
\left(
\begin{eqnarray}
1 & 1 & 1 & 2
\end{eqnarray}
\right)$$

Is there a efficient algorithm for computing the probability that the rowwise sums will be a given value?  So, If I pass the algorithm a guess at the sum (eg.

$$
\left(
\begin{eqnarray}
1\\
0\\
1\\
3 
\end{eqnarray}
\right)$$

the algorithm will return with a probability of 0 to 1.0?

Comment: What do you mean by "the upper half set to zeros?'

Comment: @Alex S:  it's a lower triangular matrix with zeros above the diagonal (see http://www.purplemath.com/modules/matrices2.htm)

Comment: do you mean the standard matrix diagonal going from top left to bottom right, or the opposite (the antidiagonal)? I ask because the example you gave does not fit your description under the standard definition.

Comment: I edited the comment. see the link